# Touch screen in Lumia 535

Tags: 8.1, 8.0, nokia-lumia-535, screen

My device is a Lumia 535. I have had this problem since I bought this mobile. The touch screen makes random and unwanted clicks. This makes it difficult to type or do some work. This usually when my hands are slightly moist which cannot be avoided in a humid weather like as in Chennai, India. I have also put a scratch guard.Is there any problem with the hardware or can I reduce the sensitivity?

Any idea as to what should I do and any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you put the screen guard before or after the problem started??

Comment: @Kelvinelove It dos not matter with the screen guard. It happens to me occasionally. It evened happened before I put a screen guard and is happening now too.

Comment: @Jayanth Locking and Unlocking your phone is temporarily stopping this problem in my phone.

Comment: So its a problem for all Lumia 535s?

Comment: Your device is Single sim or Dual sim???

Comment: Dual Sim.............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lumia 535 touchscreen problem is quite notable problem in Lumia smartphone line from Microsoft. Since I have this smartphone (Lumia 535 Dual SIM) I also acknowledge this problem.

**Short answer is:** you can't really do anything about it. I have tried to update the phone, and even install Windows 10 Mobile Preview for it, of course with no avail. This is because the problem is lies with the hardware, not the driver nor software. This problem is acknowledged from 2014 by Microsoft, but until 2016 there is no definitive fix which able to fix that problem completely for all user.

**More info:** You can read the [official FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA144183&tduid=(ec778251d5162e0913ad31e30d018b5c)(259740)(2542549)(d_wp)()) from Microsoft for this problem:

> **What to do if issues with the touch screen on my Lumia 535 and 535 Dual SIM phones?**
>
> The Lumia 535 and Lumia 535 Dual SIM display has a different behaviour to other Lumia phones in the following respect:
>
> - You cannot zoom while taking a picture.
> - Fingers should be more than 20mm apart to pinch or zoom when browsing websites or viewing pictures.
>
> The software update released in December 2014 brought some improvements to the touch sensitivity, but if you still have problems with the touch screen, or the display is not working properly, please check the following:
>
> - Check that there's no water drops or moisture on the touch panel. Wipe out the water drops and moisture to get the touch panel to function normally.
> - When typing on the keyboard, take care that you tap the center of the key. Otherwise a wrong key may get pressed if typing too fast.
> - If the screen gets magnified or zoomed when typing, check if the Screen Magnifier is enabled. You can turn the feature on and off in **Settings > Ease of access > Screen Magnifier**.
> - When charging, use the original charger coming with the phone. The touch screen may perform poorly if charging with an 3rd party charger that is not compatible with the phone.
> - Check also that all the phone updates have been installed (**Settings > Phone update > Check for updates**).

Source: [FAQ - What to do if issues with the touch screen on my Lumia 535 and 535 Dual SIM phones?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA144183&tduid=(ec778251d5162e0913ad31e30d018b5c)(259740)(2542549)(d_wp)())

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating your phone. Specially Display and Touch apps. Try decreasing the sensitivity of touch to normal. Also update your device, if any firmware or system update is pending. This may be happening because you may have set the touch app at high sensitivity. If these doesn't work try resetting you device if your device is highly misbehaving like this.

Comment: How do I change sensitivity?

Comment: From Touch setting in the Main Settings in your phone.

Comment: There is only wake up and navigation bar. No sensitivity option

Comment: It should be there. Try Updating Touch Setting from store app as I said in my Answer.

Comment: All updates are done

Comment: When you open Touch settings there should be Touch sensitivity option on top of all settings options in touch settings. However try sending snapshot of your touch settings option.

Comment: @Amandeep That option is only available on phones that support super sensitive touch. The Lumia 535 is not one of them (see [official specs](https://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/phone/lumia535/specifications)).

Answer (score 0):

Approach any authorized servicer and ask them to clean the dust off the touch panel. If the problem still persist, do comment here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything, I have Lumia 535 too, and i have that problem. The problem is in hardware not in software so you can't update it. Try with some screen protector.